# Flat tree of objects while keeping father and child

Tags: java, recursion, tree, java-stream

I have a class Employee which has a tree structure with property `team`

```
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private List<Employee> team;
}
```

Using Java lambdas I need to flat this tree into same level list while converting Employee class into the following ConvertedEmployee while storing names in dedicated `lead` and `subordinates` properties. So ConvertedEmployee is in some sense a node which keeps parent and children. And I need to have a list of those.

```
    public class ConvertedEmployee {

    private String name;
    private String lead;
    private List<String> subordinatesNames;
}
```

So final result should be `List<ConvertedEmployee>`

I was thinking to use recursion here.

But I can only flat the tree and can't rebuild it's parents.

**EDIT**:
Input is instance of Employee object that basically has a tree inside `team`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-recursive solution using concatenation of the streams followed by filtering out the "duplicated" entries which do not have `lead` field set:

```java
public static List<ConvertedEmployee> convert(List<Employee> staff) {
    return staff
        .stream()
        .flatMap(e -> Stream.concat(
            // subordinates of current employee
            e.getTeam()
             .stream()
             .map(sub -> new ConvertedEmployee(
                 sub.getName(), e.getName(),
                 sub.getTeam().stream().map(Employee::getName).collect(Collectors.toList())
             )),
            // current employee by themself
            Stream.of(new ConvertedEmployee(
                 e.getName(), null,
                 e.getTeam().stream().map(Employee::getName).collect(Collectors.toList())
            ))
        ))
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.toMap(
                ConvertedEmployee::getName,
                c -> c,
                (e1, e2) -> e1.getLead() != null ? e1 : e2.getLead() != null ? e2 : e1,
                LinkedHashMap::new
            ),
            map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values())
        ));
}
```

Test for the following setup:

```java
Employee intern = new Employee("intern", Collections.emptyList());
Employee junior = new Employee("junior", Collections.emptyList());
Employee middleDev = new Employee("mid", Arrays.asList(junior));
Employee devOps = new Employee("devOps", Collections.emptyList());
Employee teamLead = new Employee("teamLead", Arrays.asList(intern, middleDev));
Employee pm = new Employee("mgr", Arrays.asList(teamLead, devOps));

List<Employee> staff = Arrays.asList(intern, junior, middleDev, devOps, teamLead, pm);

convert(staff).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
ConvertedEmployee(name=intern, lead=teamLead, subordinatesNames=[])
ConvertedEmployee(name=junior, lead=mid, subordinatesNames=[])
ConvertedEmployee(name=mid, lead=teamLead, subordinatesNames=[junior])
ConvertedEmployee(name=devOps, lead=mgr, subordinatesNames=[])
ConvertedEmployee(name=teamLead, lead=mgr, subordinatesNames=[intern, mid])
ConvertedEmployee(name=mgr, lead=null, subordinatesNames=[teamLead, devOps])
```

Comment: Nearly the point when I would personally recommend preferring a for loop approach rather than force-fitting a solution with streams.

Comment: logic is very similar to what is needed thanks!, just that input is not a list of employees but one root employee that has tree inside of `team`